# Copying Headers to all but two worksheets in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and have been using the recorder. I have created macros that create a new sheet for each salesman.

I need the format of the combined data wks to copy to all but 2 worksheets in the workbook.

```
Sub Headings()
  'Headings Macro
  Sheets("PipelineReport").Select
  Range("B2:N2").Select
  Selection.Copy
```

**How can i paste to all sheets except "PipelineReport" & "Raw Data"??

Comment: Loop on the worksheets, check their names and use `PasteSpecial`. Search SO for plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

The code would to be like this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim vDB
    vDB = Sheets("PipelineReport").Range("b2").Resize(1, 14)
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        If Ws.Name = "PipelineReport" Or Ws.Name = "Raw Data" Then
        Else
            Ws.Range("b2").Resize(1, 14) = vDB
        End If
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Set rngDB = Sheets("PipelineReport").Range("b2").Resize(1, 14)
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        If Ws.Name = "PipelineReport" Or Ws.Name = "Raw Data" Then
        Else
           rngDB.Copy Ws.Range("b2")
        End If
    Next Ws
End Sub
```